# loading data.sql and schema.sql on load with Spring boot 2.1.4 RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've found couple of answers but unfortunately none of them is working for me.

My application properties is set to

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Problem: My `resources/data.sql` and `resources/schema.sql` is not loaded.

Wondering if there's another configuration setting that i'm missing.

Comment: You approach seems on right track. Is it possible for you put your code into github so, I have can take a code and have a look?

Comment: Actually these configurations from your application.properties are not needed just for simple execution of schema.sql and data.sql. Spring Boot can automatically create the schema (DDL scripts) of your DataSource and initialize it (DML scripts). It loads SQL from the standard root classpath locations: schema.sql and data.sql, respectively - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc Also you can follow this guide - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql

Comment: How do you launch  the app?

Comment: @ShaunakPatel you can download from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/79t5as7yfotzowu/reservations.zip?dl=0

Comment: to test -> run this in browser `api/reservations/2017-01-01`

Comment: @EugenCovaci i launch from intellij using default configuration that it builds automatically

Comment: SQL is loading correctly from your files. Why do you think it doesn't work? I've added spring.h2.console.enabled=true to app.prop to enable h2 console and could see all your data in console after execution of project - http://localhost:8080/h2-console/

Comment: @gines.nt because I don't see this in my spring boot console `o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL`. by the way h2-console is not showing anything on my end, how do you enable that?

Comment: Now I'll share reservations2 (the exercise I'm following) and it works and I see all sql and schema related messages in the console. The difference between my version and this version (reservation2) is that my version uses latest spring 2 minus some additional RestControllers. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ua7r81fpa4shkk5/reservations2.zip?dl=0. I'm confused that my version works fine on your system and not here.

Comment: i was able to get h2 console working. https://medium.com/@harittweets/how-to-connect-to-h2-database-during-development-testing-using-spring-boot-44bbb287570